# ViewTable don't read array (IOS)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, tableview

I had 2 programs, the first one read JSON online and save it into array. The second program complete `UITableView` with array, but when I join don't work.

When I debug I look the table do first, but I have the son method first.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,    UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String > ()

let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.learnswiftonline.com/Samples/subway.json")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {

            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                if let stations = json["stations"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    for station in stations {

                        if let name = station["stationName"] as? String {

                            if let year = station["buildYear"] as? String {
                                self.TableData.append(name + "[" + year + "]")
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")

            }

          /*  for element in TableData {
                print(element)
            }*/

        }




    }
    task.resume()



    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[row]

    return cell
}

 }
```

On my emulator just see the empty table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your not reloading the tableView. The HTTP request will take sometime to complete.

Once your request has completed call `self.tableView.reloadData()`.

It will be on another queue so use

```
 NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
      self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Place it

```
// Stuff above...

if let stations = json["stations"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

    for station in stations {

        if let name = station["stationName"] as? String {

            if let year = station["buildYear"] as? String {
                self.TableData.append(name + "[" + year + "]")
            }
        }
    }

    // Do your reload here.. as your array will have finished populating
}

// Stuff below..
```

Comment: Expected declaration, how can I declare?

Comment: Sounds like you put it someplace thats out of scope to the method

Comment: Also don't capitalise variable names, TableData ... should be tableData. You can also declare like this - var tableData =  [String]() ... much cleaner imo

Comment: Compiles, but still empty